# can python asyncio data_received receive all data which client sent

Tags: python, python-3.x, asynchronous, python-asyncio

I am learning python asyncio module and try to write a socks5 server with it. Python docs said:

> Called when some data is received. data is a non-empty bytes object
>   containing the incoming data.

I wonder when client sends 2 bytes data, will `data_received(self, data)` just receive 1 byte not 2 bytes when it called and the rest 1 byte will call `data_received(self, data)` again?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import asyncio
import logging
import socket
import struct

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG,
                    format='{asctime} {levelname} {message}',
                    datefmt='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S',
                    style='{')


class Remote(asyncio.Protocol):
    def connection_made(self, transport):
        self.transport = transport
        self.server_transport = None

    def data_received(self, data):
        self.server_transport.write(data)


class Server(asyncio.Protocol):
    INIT, REQUEST, REPLY = 0, 1, 2

    def connection_made(self, transport):
        client_info = transport.get_extra_info('peername')
        logging.info('connect from {}'.format(client_info))
        self.transport = transport
        self.state = self.INIT

    def data_received(self, data):
        if self.state == self.INIT:
            if data[0] == 5:
                amount = data[1]    # Authentication amount
                if 0 in data[2:]:
                    self.transport.write(b'\x05\x00')
                    self.state = self.REQUEST

                else:
                    self.eof_received()
            else:
                self.eof_received()

        elif self.state == self.REQUEST:
            ver, cmd, rsv, addr_type = data[:4]
            logging.info('addr type: {}'.format(addr_type))
            if addr_type == 1:    # ipv4
                addr = socket.inet_ntoa(data[4:8])

            elif addr_type == 3:
                addr_len = data[4]
                addr = data[5:5+addr_len]

            else:
                data = b'\x05\x08\x00\x01'
                data += socket.inet_aton('0.0.0.0') + struct.pack('>H', 0)
                self.transport.write(data)
                logging.error('not support addr type')
                self.eof_received()

            port = struct.unpack('>H', data[-2:])[0]
            logging.info('target: {}:{}'.format(addr, port))
            asyncio.ensure_future(self.remote(addr, port))
            self.state = self.REPLY

        elif self.state == self.REPLY:
            logging.info('start relay')
            self.remote_transport.write(data)

    async def remote(self, addr, port):
        loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        transport, _remote = await loop.create_connection(Remote, addr, port)
        _remote.server_transport = self.transport
        self.remote_transport = transport
        bind_addr, bind_port = transport.get_extra_info('sockname')
        data = b'\x05\x00\x00\x01'
        data += socket.inet_aton(bind_addr) + struct.pack('>H', bind_port)
        self.transport.write(data)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    server = loop.create_server(Server, '127.0.0.2', 1089)
    loop.run_until_complete(server)

    try:
        loop.run_forever()

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        server.close()
        loop.run_until_complete(server.close())
        loop.close()
```

Answer (score 2):

no, `data_received` will receive as many bytes as are already received by the server. If you need to receive the first 3 bytes to handle the request, then you should implement some buffering in your Protocol to allow you to wait for the rest of the request to arrive before continuing.

It would typically look like this:

```
def __init__(self, …):
    self._buffer = bytearray()
    …

def data_received(self, data):
    self._buffer += data

    if self.state == self.INIT:
        # here we need at least 3 bytes.
        # if we don't have enough data yet, just wait for the next `data_received` call
        if len(self._buffer) < 3:
            return

        header, self._buffer = self._buffer[:2], self._buffer[2:]
        # parse authentication header, switch the state to REQUEST

    elif self.state == self.REQUEST:
        …
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, I implemented a data_buf to make sure I receive all data now.